# click and closeclick event on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs3

I want to open two infowindows on the same marker. On 'click' event first infowindow should close  (which I am showing already on map) and open the second infowindow. On closing the second infowindow, I'd like to open the first window.

Here is my code:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content,
            marker:marker,
            maxWidth: 300,
            image:image,
            id:vehicleNo
        });         
var openinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentone,
            marker:marker,
            maxWidth: 300,
            image:image,
            id:vehicleNo
        }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){         
                return function() {                             
                    openinfowindow.close();                 
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };              
        })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
            openinfowindow.setContent(contentone);
            openinfowindow.open(map,marker);                                
    });
```

Comment: What is the issue? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the only difference between the infowindows is the desired content, you may use a single infowindow and simply toggle the content:

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        contents:[content,contentOne],
        marker:marker,
        maxWidth: 300,
        image:image,
        id:vehicleNo
    });         

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,
                                                            contents,
                                                            infowindow){         
      return function() {                                       
                infowindow.contents=[contents[0],contents[1]];
                infowindow.setContent(contents[0]);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
      };              
    })(marker,infowindow.contents,infowindow)); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
        var that=this;
        that.contents.reverse();
        that.setContent(this.contents[0]);
        setTimeout(function(){
          that.open(map,marker);},
          100);                                
    });
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/affgpsvt/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/affgpsvt/)

Comment: Its working only for single marker but not for multiple marker

Comment: What exactly do we need to do for multiple marker? plz help me out